# How to understand the phrase "the unwilling objects of a gruesome sort of reflected fame"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> There were relatives of their victims among the Hogwarts students, who now found themselves **the unwilling objects of a gruesome sort of reflected fame** as they walked the corridors: Susan Bones, whose uncle, aunt and cousins had all died at the hands of one of the ten, said miserably during Herbology that she now had a good idea what it felt like to be Harry.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't quite understand the phrase "*the unwilling objects of a gruesome sort of reflected fame*". How should we understand it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working backwards through that phrase

- **reflected fame** means they became famous because their relatives
  were well known.
- **a gruesome sort of reflected fame** means the death of their relatives was
  unpleasant.
- **the unwilling objects of a gruesome sort of reflected fame** means
  they did not want that fame.

A complementary situation could be, say, the son of movie stars, famous because of who his parents are, and loving the attention it brings.

Comment: How can 'objects' describe persons?

Comment: Consider the phrase "she was the object of my affections". The word "object" does not just mean "thing". As in **subject** — **object**.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a lot is packed into that phrase:

1. The students have obtained a kind of fame.
2. The fame is **reflected** in that it is really the victims who are famous, not the surviving students.
3. They were **unwilling**, they didn't want this fame.
4. The fame was of a **gruesome** sort because it derived from tragedy and horror, not some positive achievement.